# Kinda complicated tar based on modified date

Tags: bash, find, tar

Okay, I think this is possible, but I can't quite figure it out. This is the situation.

A folder contains the log files of all the processes on my robot. The structure looks sort of like this:

```
$ ls -lrt
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 per per 4096 nov  3 12:46 launch01
-rw-rw-r-- 1 per per    0 nov  3 12:47 camera112.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 per per    0 nov  3 12:47 motors121.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 per per    0 nov  3 12:47 lidar111.log
drwxrwxr-x 2 per per 4096 nov  3 12:49 launch02
-rw-rw-r-- 1 per per    0 nov  3 12:49 motors122.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 per per    0 nov  3 12:49 lidar211.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 per per    0 nov  3 12:49 camera113.log
```

The files `camera112.log`, `motors121.log` and `lidar111.log` are associated to the logs in folder `launch01`. I would like to write a script that gets all the files that belong to a specific launch and tar them into one tarball. Since timestamps can change between slightly by files and the numbers in the files are only nearly related, I think the best way to gather all relevant files is to get all files which are below `launch01` (inclusive), up to the next directory in the list (exclusive). The number of files can vary, as can the time stamps and names. What is consistent is the folder, then a bunch of files, then the next folder, then files, etc. Ultimately, I would like to get the latest set of logs easily.

Unsure of the approach here. Any ideas how to go about this?

Clarifications:

- Number of files can vary.
- The exact timestamp is not reliable (as above, the folder `launch01` is different than `camera112.log`) but relative timestamps work fine. For instance, if I could tar all files from `launch01`                                                          (inclusive) to `launch02` (exclusive) in the list provided by `ls -lrt`, that works great.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please elaborate what you mean by _"timestamps can change between slightly by files"_. Do you mean the timestamps are no reliable means to associate the files belonging together? The sort order of the `ls -lrt` command uses the timestamps, so if you can't rely on them ...

Comment: "_all files which are below `launch01`_" presumably you mean "_all files that are_ newer _than `launch01`_"? Above and below have only visual meaning

Comment: Adding to @Theophrastus comment, maybe there's another way of linking the files to the folders that don't rely on something so unreliable as the dates; if you can think such option exists.

Comment: @roaima - "*all files which are below `launch01`*" - I took that to be referring to the visual of the output of `ls -lrt`... so, below `launch01/` and above `launch02/` ("*up to the next directory in the list*")

Comment: @Greenonline oh yes, I completely missed that possibility; I was looking at the set of files shown in the question

Comment: I have a Perl solution for something very similar to this that I faced earlier in the year, which is a sort of look ahead loop, with a "previous value" variable used to backstep - which I *could* modify and post, if you aren't looking for a bash only solution. However, it would be better to just rename the files - if you have control over the log writing code - to match the `launch<n>`, i.e. `camera<n>112.log`, etc.. Also, how sure are you that a log for `launch01` could **never** appear after `launch02`? Is it logically impossible, w.r.t. thread timings, or whatever?

Answer (score 1):

Splitting the task into chunks, using your input of

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 per per 4096 nov  3 12:46 launch01
-rw-rw-r-- 1 per per    0 nov  3 12:47 camera112.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 per per    0 nov  3 12:47 motors121.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 per per    0 nov  3 12:47 lidar111.log
drwxrwxr-x 2 per per 4096 nov  3 12:49 launch02
-rw-rw-r-- 1 per per    0 nov  3 12:49 motors122.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 per per    0 nov  3 12:49 lidar211.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 per per    0 nov  3 12:49 camera113.log
```

#### Create the "ordered" list of the filenames only

Use either one of these:

```
ls -lrt | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f9
ls -lrt | awk '{print $9}'
```

gives:

```
launch01
camera112.log
motors121.log
lidar111.log
launch02
motors122.log
lidar211.log
camera113.log
```

#### Farm the list off into sections

Modifying this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11314801/4424636) to [Split one file into multiple files based on delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11313852/4424636), create a file called `awk_pattern` containing the following:

```
BEGIN{ fn = "part1.txt"; n = 1 }
{
   if (substr($0,1,6) == "launch") {
       close (fn)
       n++
       fn = "part" n ".txt"
   }
   print > fn
}
```

and then running

```
ls -lrt | awk '{print $9}' | awk -f awk_pattern
```

gives the required output:

`part1.txt`

```
launch01
```

and then

`part2.txt`

```
launch01
camera112.log
motors121.log
lidar111.log
```

`part3.txt`

```
launch02
motors122.log
lidar211.log
camera113.log
```

Although the first file (`part1.txt`) should be discarded as it contains only one line...

```
rm part1.txt
```

#### tar the contents of each part

From [6.3 Reading Names from a File](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/files.html)

```
tar -c -v -z -T part2.txt -f part2.tgz
```

#### Looping through the tar files

```bsh
for part_file in $(ls part*)
do
  tar_file = ${part_file%.*}
#  tar_file = basename ${part_file} .txt
  tar -c -v -z -T ${part_file} -f ${tar_file}.tgz
done
```

This should give

```
part1.tgz
part2.tgz
part3.tgz
```

Again, `part1.tgz` should be discarded:

```
rm part1.tgz
```

#### Putting it all together

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

ls -lrt | awk '{print $9}' | awk -f awk_pattern

for part_file in $(ls part*)
do
  tar_file = ${part_file%.*}
  tar -c -v -z -T ${part_file} -f ${tar_file}.tgz
done


rm part1.txt
rm part1.tgz
```

As just one script (incorporating the awk pattern)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

ls -lrt | awk '{print $9}' | awk 'BEGIN{ fn = "part1.txt"; n = 1 }
{
   if (substr($0,1,6) == "launch") {
       close (fn)
       n++
       fn = "part" n ".txt"
   }
   print > fn
}'

for part_file in $(ls part*)
do
  tar_file = ${part_file%.*}
  tar -c -v -z -T ${part_file} -f ${tar_file}.tgz
done

rm part1.txt
rm part1.tgz
```

This (hopefully) *should* work, although I have only tested the first two steps, i.e. up to the tar part, as I don't have the files to tarball up.

---

#### Possible improvements:

1. *Post-processing*: Remove the `part*.txt` files (`rm part*.txt`)
2. *Post-processing*: Remove the log files once tar'd up (`rm *.log`)
3. *Post-processing*: Remove the directories once tar'd up (`rm -R -- */`)

   See this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68847/97255) to [How do I remove all sub-directories from within a directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68846/97255).
4. Prevent awk from producing the useless `part1.txt` file
5. Save the tar files elsewhere (`... -f ${tar_path}/${tar_file}.tgz`)
6. Don't use intermediary `part*.txt` files.

Comment: Tested on OS X.