# Why does `zip` in a for loop work when the file exists, but not when it doesn't?

Tags: shell-script, shell, zsh, quoting, zip

I have a directory that contains several sub-directories. There is [a question about zipping the files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68490/5788) that contains an answer that I ever-so-slightly modified for my needs.

```
for i in */; do zip "zips/${i%/}.zip" "$i*.csv"; done
```

However, I run into a bizarre problem. For the first set of folders, where `zips/<name>.zip` does not exist, I get this error:

```
zip error: Nothing to do! (zips/2014-10.zip)
        zip warning: name not matched: 2014-11/*.csv
```

*however* when I just `echo` the zip statements:

```
for i in */; do echo zip "zips/${i%/}.zip" "$i*.csv"; done
```

Then run the echoed command (`zip zips/2014-10.zip 2014-10/*.csv`), it works fine and zips up the folder. Then the fun part about that is that subsequent runs of the original command *will* actually zip up folders that didn't work the first time!

To test this behavior yourself:

```
cd /tmp
mkdir -p 2016-01 2016-02 2016-03 zips
for i in 2*/; do touch "$i"/one.csv; done
for i in 2*/; do touch "$i"/two.csv; done
zip zips/2016-03.zip 2016-03/*.csv
for i in 2*/; do echo zip "zips/${i%/}.zip" "$i*.csv"; done
for i in 2*/; do zip "zips/${i%/}.zip" "$i*.csv"; done
```

You'll see that the echo prints these statements:

```
zip zips/2016-01.zip 2016-01/*.csv
zip zips/2016-02.zip 2016-02/*.csv
zip zips/2016-03.zip 2016-03/*.csv
```

However, the actual zip command will tell you:

```
        zip warning: name not matched: 2016-01/*.csv

zip error: Nothing to do! (zips/2016-01.zip)
        zip warning: name not matched: 2016-02/*.csv

zip error: Nothing to do! (zips/2016-02.zip)
updating: 2016-03/one.csv (stored 0%)
updating: 2016-03/two.csv (stored 0%)
```

So it's actually updating the zip file with the `.csv`s where the zip file exists, but *not* when the zip file is created. And if you copy one of the zip commands:

```
$ zip zips/2016-02.zip 2016-02/*.csv
adding: 2016-02/one.csv (stored 0%)
adding: 2016-02/two.csv (stored 0%)
```

Then re-run the zip-all-the-things:

```
for i in 2*/; do zip "zips/${i%/}.zip" "$i*.csv"; done
```

You'll see that it updates for `2016-02` and `2016-03`. Here's my output of `tree`:

```
.
├── 2016-01
│   ├── one.csv
│   └── two.csv
├── 2016-02
│   ├── one.csv
│   └── two.csv
├── 2016-03
│   ├── one.csv
│   └── two.csv
└── zips
    ├── 2016-02.zip
    └── 2016-03.zip
```

Also, (un)surprisingly, this works just fine:

```
zsh -c "$(for i in 2*/; do echo zip "zips/${i%/}.zip" "$i*.csv"; done)"
```

What am I doing wrong here? (note, I am using zsh instead of bash, if that makes any difference)

Comment: Could you show the exact "echoed command" that it output and you successfully ran?

Comment: @JigglyNaga `zip zips/2014-10.zip 2014-10/*.csv` (also added to the Q)

Comment: The error is about no `*cvs` file existing, not about missing `.zip`. Could you give us a minimal example of the directory/file structure you're using so we can recreate it and test the error?

Comment: @terdon done - steps to repro, along with the output of tree. It seems like a very strange behavior to me. If it were simply a matter of somehow the command was in the wrong directory, I'd expect that it fail for *all* of the zip files, but it does work for the ones that are manually created...

Comment: Added a workaround... but why doesn't the original work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Expansion by the shell

The quotes around `"$i*.csv"` make the difference.  With the quotes, the shell expands that string to "2014-11/*.csv".  That exact file doesn't exist, and `zip` reports an error.  Without quotes, the `*` also expands (via filename expansion/"globbing"), and the resulting `zip` command is a complete list of matching files, each as a separate argument.  You can get the second behaviour, inside the `for` loop, with:

```
for i in */ ; do zip "zips/${i%/}.zip" "$i"*.csv ; done
```

## Expansion by zip

`zip` can also expand wildcards for itself, but not in all situations.  From the [zip manual](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/zip.html):

> The *zip* program can do the same matching on names that are in the *zip* archive being modified or, in the case of the **-x** (exclude) or **-i** (include) options, on the list of files to be operated on, by using backslashes or quotes to tell the shell not to do the name expansion.

The original command works on subsequent attempts, after you've successfully created an archive, because `zip` tries to match the wildcards against the contents of the existing archive.  They exist there, and still exist on the filesystem, so they're reported with `updating:`.

To get `zip` to handle the wildcards when *creating* the archive, use the `-r` (recurse) option to recurse into the requested directory, and `-i` (include) to limit it to files matching the pattern:

```
 for i in */ ; do zip -r "zips/${i%/}.zip" "$i" -i '*.csv' ; done
```