# Terminal - Zip files with special characters in password

Tags: shell-script, password, zip

So I had this question earlier and it got answered "[Terminal - Zip multiple directories into separate zip files with password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370253/terminal-zip-multiple-directories-into-separate-zip-files-with-password)" however I couldn't find out how I can use a password with special characters like !@#$. I tried the typical solutions:

- Enclose the whole password string in " " or ' '
- / before every special character.

Nothing worked.
This is the command that worked for me except that the password was never set correct (in my attempts it was either set to something different from what I intended, or wasn't set all together)

```
for i in */; do zip -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i" -p "mypassword!@#$" ; done
```

Comment: Did you try / or \ ???

Comment: \ I believe. Which one is the correct?

Comment: The correct is this form \ please edit your answer, and make sure you are using the correct form.... do you used the zip command to make the password too? Maybe some character are not really included at the password (being ignored at the compression utility), so you can try without some of it. The right way is something like this: mypassword\!\@\#\$

Comment: Did you try using `'strong quotes'` rather than `"weak quotes"` around the password?  Alternatively, put the password into a variable and use `-p "$password"`.

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini Worked well. Not sure what was wrong earlier. You can go ahead and reply to my question as an answer so I can pick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using "/" instead of "\", so the right solution will be like this:

```
 mypassword\!\@\#\$
```