# zip files within all sub-directories of a given parent directory

Tags: shell-script, scripting, zip, recursive

Say I have a `parent_directory/` with the following sub-directories `child1/`, `child2/` and `child3/`.

How do I script to `zip` all `*.txt` files in `childx/` into `childx.zip`
I also want this `childx.zip` to be located in its `childx/` directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [command to zip multiple directories into individual zip files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68489/command-to-zip-multiple-directories-into-individual-zip-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Sample data

```
$ mkdir -p parent_directory/child{1..3}
$ touch parent_directory/child{1..3}/file1.txt
$ touch parent_directory/child{1..3}/file2.txt

$ tree parent_directory/
parent_directory/
├── child1
│   ├── file1.txt
│   └── file2.txt
├── child2
│   ├── file1.txt
│   └── file2.txt
└── child3
    ├── file1.txt
    └── file2.txt

3 directories, 6 files
```

#### Solution

Now to script the zip files:

```
$ cd parent_directory/; for i in *; do find ${i} -name "*.txt" -print | zip ${i}.zip -@; mv ${i}.zip ${i}; done; cd -
  adding: child1/file2.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: child1/file1.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: child2/file2.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: child2/file1.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: child3/file2.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: child3/file1.txt (stored 0%)
```

#### Results

And the results:

```
$ tree parent_directory/
parent_directory/
├── child1
│   ├── child1.zip
│   ├── file1.txt
│   └── file2.txt
├── child2
│   ├── child2.zip
│   ├── file1.txt
│   └── file2.txt
└── child3
    ├── child3.zip
    ├── file1.txt
    └── file2.txt

3 directories, 9 files

$ unzip -l parent_directory/child1/child1.zip
Archive:  parent_directory/child1/child1.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  07-05-2018 10:08   child1/file2.txt
        0  07-05-2018 10:08   child1/file1.txt
---------                     -------
        0                     2 files
$ unzip -l parent_directory/child2/child2.zip
Archive:  parent_directory/child2/child2.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  07-05-2018 10:08   child2/file2.txt
        0  07-05-2018 10:08   child2/file1.txt
---------                     -------
        0                     2 files
$ unzip -l parent_directory/child3/child3.zip
Archive:  parent_directory/child3/child3.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  07-05-2018 10:08   child3/file2.txt
        0  07-05-2018 10:08   child3/file1.txt
---------                     -------
        0                     2 files
```

#### References

- https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip

Comment: follow-up question: child1/ has additional sub-directories (and these might have sub-directories too), and I'd like the script to do the same on these sub-directories as well, recursively. Would a simple -r do it? and where would I place it in the command?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$ zip -R parent_directory '*.txt'
```