# Create loop for 2000+ folders with incremental names to zip into archives with the same incremental names

Tags: bash

I'm a total bash and SE beginner and in need some help, please.
I have more than 2000 folders (their names are incrementals of 1000) on a Debian server, which I need to zip to separate store-only archives with the corresponding incremental names in the folder 1 level-up the hierarchy from the source. Then I need source files folders deleted after each archive is created.

So, below code works for what I need but my current idea is to repeat the same line over 2000 times. I'd like to know if there is a better way to automate this process into just a few extra lines with the use of a loop and I guess a sub-folder variable?

Any help appreciated, please. Thank you very much!

```
#!/bin/bash

cd private/completed/0/ && zip -r -0 ../0.zip ./* && rm -R 0/ && cd -
cd private/completed/1000/ && zip -r -0 ../1000.zip ./* && rm -R ../1000 && cd -
cd private/completed/2000/ && zip -r -0 ../2000.zip ./* && rm -R ../2000 && cd -
cd private/completed/3000/ && zip -r -0 ../3000.zip ./* && rm -R ../3000 && cd -
cd private/completed/4000/ && zip -r -0 ../4000.zip ./* && rm -R ../4000 && cd -
....

cd private/completed/2800000/ && zip -r -0 ../2800000.zip ./* && rm -R ../2800000 && cd -
```

**UPDATE:** Thank you very much for the helpful link, Kusalananda ([command to zip multiple directories into individual zip files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68489/command-to-zip-multiple-directories-into-individual-zip-files)). I used the code from that related answer and slightly modified it to make it work exactly how I need it. I added the resulting code below:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd private/completed/
for i in {0..2800000..1000}; do echo "$i" ; cd "$i" ; zip -q -r -0 ../"${i%/}.zip" . && cd .. && rm -R "$i" ; done
```

Comment: select the code block and then click `{}`. remove ` enclosing each line.

Comment: Are there folders with names like `1`, `2`, etc., i.e. with sequence numbers between the ones with step 1000?

Comment: The folders are "0", "1000", "2000" with a step of 1000 and they go all the way up to "28000000".

Comment: So there is no `1` folder, or `1500` etc.?

Comment: No, no such folders.

Comment: Ok, so the issue could be formulated as "create a Zip file for each folder under `private/completed` regardless of the folder's name".

Comment: Yes, as long as each zip filename is the same as corresponding source folder name. Plus deleting the source folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68489/command-to-zip-multiple-directories-into-individual-zip-files  (with the "single directory" being your `private/completed` directory).

Comment: Thank you for the link, Kusalananda. It was very helpful. I used the code from a related answer you linked to and slightly modified it to make it work exactly how I need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the for loop; like so; for example : seq start step end

```
for  i in `seq 1000 1000 2000000`;do echo $i; done;
```

You can use your cp command and use $i for directory name and foldername

Comment: Thank you for help, Sandeep. Sorry, I'm really green in bash. I just happen to have to work with a Debian server since yesterday and need to solve an everyday automation problem. So, I kind of really need a ready-to-paste code :-)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Thank you very much for the helpful link, Kusalananda ([command to zip multiple directories into individual zip files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68489/command-to-zip-multiple-directories-into-individual-zip-files)). I used the code from that related answer and slightly modified it to make it work exactly how I need it. I added the resulting code below:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd private/completed/
for i in {0..2800000..1000}; do echo "$i" ; cd "$i" ; zip -q -r -0 ../"${i%/}.zip" . && cd .. && rm -R "$i" ; done
```